# Adicionar + opções no editor de postagem do Wordpress e exibi-las no Tema

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Ou seja, o editor de postagem do WordPress padrão e só aquilo..]
Mas como posso colocar opção na hora de postar, como informe o link link de download.. ai a gente coloca ele na hora de postar, e pode exibir depois no tema.

TIPO ASSIM:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e depois poder exir essas informações no tema, dentro da postagem. (OU SEJA, CADA POSTAGEM VAI TER O SEU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem um plugin chamado BookReview que cria esta tabela ai em cada post, só pra livros. Vale dar uma olhada nele e adaptar os campos para áudios, filmes, etc...